# Strange behaviour after recursively calling another makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, multiple-makefiles

I have a main makefile in the root directory of my project. There is another makefile inside the *include* directory. The second makefile uses the include keyword to call some other makefiles in other projects which I have no control over it. I cannot directly include this makefile as it has some targets which have the same name as the ones that I have. As a workaround, I decided to use recursive calling. When I run this makefile through the shell, using the following command, it works nicely:

```
my_project$ make -C include -f Second_Makefile
```

But when I call it through the main Makefile as follows, it does not behave normally meaning that it reports some project specific errors rooted from the included files inside the second makefile which are very hard to locate.

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) -C include -f Second_Makefile
```

I also tried the following line, but it did not help:

```
cd include; @$(MAKE) -f Second_Makefile
```

I think there should be difference between recursive calling and direct calling but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Is that the entire main makefile?

Comment: Is this an error in `Second_Makefile` or in the main makefile? If you replace `all`'s command with to just `echo`, will it run successfully? You might take a look at the options passed to the sub-make by adding `echo $(MAKEFLAGS)` before the sub-make invocation. I also find the `-np` flags particularly useful for debugging environment differences.

Comment: As I said, error comes from one of the files included inside `Second_Makefile`. Indeed, if I put a simple `echo` it works. Content of `MAKEFLAGS` is `w --`. I also tried to make the using the following syntax without any success: `@$(MAKE) -C include -f Second_Makefile MAKEFLAGS=`.

Comment: This will be difficult to diagnose. I suspect that one of the distant makefiles is doing something unwise with `MAKELEVEL`. As a work-around, could you create a new makefile in the root directory, which would `include Second_Makefile` and `$(MAKE) -f First_Makefile`?

Comment: That indeed worked because including another makefile is equivalent to running it directly. Also, I manually set `MAKELEVEL=-1` in the First_Makefile but it did not help.